# Using the "this" keyword in a different class c#

Tags: c#, xaml

I made a program that works just fine as-is, however i want to organize code better by moving some of my logic into other .cs files;  upon moving some code i noticed that code reffering the "this" keyword for changing the applications width / height no longer function and ive had no luck trying to get a handle to "this", please help

```
int heightd = (int)this.Height;
```

Edit: To further clarify. My mainwindow.xaml.cs  is where all my code was before.
I would use this.width  to get my windows width.

Upon creating a different .cs file to hold related methods, it  broke all of my "this" refferences.

I want for my NEW cs file to be able to get a handle on "this" from my main program. so i can call its width, height, etc

Re-edit: I understand that "this" is not going to function properly from my new class I just want to be able to create methods that use the same object that is accessed when "this" is refferenced.
So for example, Class2 can do WorkAround.height ;   where WorkAround is a handle to whatever "this" is in class 1.

Soution:  updated signature in new class to accept the main window:

```
public static void Marginnn(MainWindow aplication)
    {
```

send "this" from main class during the call:

```
WindowsInterop.Marginnn(this);
```

Comment: Modify the class to accept a reference to the original object and then operate on that reference.

Comment: The amount of details you included is not enough for us to be able to help properly.

Comment: I edited it in hopes of having sufficient details now;
The secondary class holds static methods so i dont instantiate it; i use it to operate on things

Comment: i dont know what is your design but shouldnt you be thinking about partial classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have discussed partial classes, which can be problematic.  For this answer, I assume by "move to another .cs file" you mean "move to another class," as your title indicates.

The `this` keyword is effectively a variable that refers to the instance that "owns" the current method.  If the method is moved to another type, then the instance can no longer be the owner of the method.  Instead, you need to pass a reference to the instance into the method instead.  That will be a method parameter, which will have a name other than `this`.

Example; before:

```
class App
{
    public void DoSomethingWithTheHeight()
    {
        int heightd = (int)this.Height;
        //more code
    }
    public void CallDoSomethingWithTheHeight()
    {
        this.DoSomethingWithTheHeight();
    }
}
```

Task: move DoSomethingWithTheHeight to a new static class:

```
class App
{
    public void CallDoSomethingWithTheHeight()
    {
        NewClass.DoSomethingWithTheHeight(this);
    }
}

static class NewClass
{
    public static void DoSomethingWithTheHeight(App application)
    {
        int heightd = (int)application.Height;
        //more code
    }
}
```

Task: move DoSomethingWithTheHeight to a new non-static class:

```
class App
{
    public void CallDoSomethingWithTheHeight()
    {
        NewClass instanceOfNewClass = new NewClass();
        instanceOfNewClass.DoSomethingWithTheHeight(this);
    }
}

class NewClass
{
    public void DoSomethingWithTheHeight(App application)
    {
        int heightd = (int)application.Height;
        //more code
    }
}
```

There are other possibilities, but these examples should illustrate the basic principle.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to move part of your class to another file and still use `this`, you have to use a partial class. But I won't recommend this approach, your code clearly needs some refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

C# keyword `this` refers to the current instance of the class it's being used in.  It can be used for a few other things such as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method, but we won't worry about that here.  So, you may only use `this` from within the class that it's referring to and note that it may not be used with `static` classes, methods, fields, etc... since they have no instance associated with them.

If the code you're referring to is not implemented within a `partial` class, then it has to refer to the instance of the `Window`.  Otherwise, it's impossible to tell what `this` is.  Since we don't know how exactly you're structuring your program, it's hard to recommend a method of fetching the instance of the `Window` in question.  If, for example, you would use the `MVVM` pattern, you wouldn't even need to interact with the instance of the UI from within the code.  However, if you're working with a code-behind model, then your best bet is probably to create a `partial` class for that window.  Like I said, it's hard to know what's right in your situation without knowing the entire scope of your environment.

There are lots of ways to tackle this and some are more hackish than others:

```
// In the code-behind of a window...
public static MyWindow Instance { get; private set; }
public MyWindow()
{
     Initialize();
     Instance = this;
}

// Somewhere else in your program...
var someValue = MyWindow.Instance.SomeControl.Value;
```

Note that the above code is just for demonstration purposes and not something I would recommend doing (it doesn't even account for `null`, but that's easy to fix).  It's simply a demonstration showing that there are almost countless ways of tackling your problem.  Ideally, if you're not going with MVVM, I would probably implement a window manager class that handles instances of all of your application windows.